# How can I navigate any JSON tree in c#?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, .net-3.5

I need to navigate a Json structure as I would navigate an XML using `XmlDocument`.

The structure is not known, and I need to iterate over the nodes to parse some data.

Is this possible?
I know I can use `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize it into a known type, but this is not the case as I can receive any valid json.

<strike>I'm using .NET 3.5 (SP1) and cannot upgrade to 4.0 at the moment.</strike>
I upgraded to .NET 4.0 to use dynamic types (which is awesomeness made code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c)

Comment: @Jason, this is not a duplicate, I specifically state that I don't know the structure so I cannot deserilize it to a known type.

Comment: Right; the linked question is centered around JSON.NET, not JavaScriptSerializer. The former allows you to walk and inspect the resulting structure, the latter is for static types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this article:

- http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

It explains you a way of parsing JSON to a dynamic object which has a dictionary inside.

So, iterating a dictionary would be nice with LINQ, wouldn't be?

--- OR IF YOU'RE IN .NET 3.5... --- ;)

Why don't you implement an extension method like "ToDictionary"?

You can receive JSON text, later parse with a regular expression and split properties and values into a dictionary, everything done with suggested extension method.

A sample of how it would work that:

```
IDictionary<string, object> deserializedJson = jsonText.ToDictionary();
```

Fits your needs?

--- EVEN YET ANOTHER TRY (now you've more options)! ---

Check this open source project on CodePlex:

- http://json.codeplex.com/

It has LINQ-to-JSON so you can read and write JSON.

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using .NET 3.5 (Edit: But I could use that JavaScriptConverter thingy, I'm going to try it)

Comment: I liked your first answer so much that I'm negotiating migrating the application to 4.0, I'll update with the results.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'll "un-strike" the first one, and I'll edit with a good "OR you can do that" ;)

Comment: Can you update your answer with explanation from the first link?

Comment: @maracuja-juice It's been a very long time since this answer haha. I see all links are broken. Honestly, I don't remember what I was talking about. But I'll try it anyway... If I can't remember the thing, I'll proceed to delete my answer.