# Alter Json or ExtensionDataObject

Tags: c#, json, iextensibledataobject

I have a Json service I cannot alter as it is not mine.
Their Json is a formatted in a way that parsing it is difficult.  It looks something like this.

```
"people": {
     "Joe Bob": {
              "name": "Joe Bob",
              "id": "12345"
     },
     "Bob Smith": {
              "name": "Bob Smith",
              "id": "54321"
     }
 },
```

I would really prefer this was laid out like a JSon array, however it presently is not.
I am wondering the best approach here.  Should I alter the Json to look like an array before I parse it or load up the ExtensionData and parse it from that?

There are other items in the feed that I do not have issue with.  Just stuck with this one section.

Thanks

Comment: mabye this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx can help? (if you wanted to loop on the items..)

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?  Deserialize it into a type?  Just loop through each key?  What exact problem are you running into?

Comment: I would like to create a List<people> with the class containing the name and id. Problem is they named the classes so that is tripping me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json.net to deserialize the data (the json you pasted, and doing only one parsing, without modifying anything).

using `dynamic foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data)`
than, you can iterate the list using `foo.people`, accessing the Name and Value.

you can create a class (if you know what the schema is, and to deserialize the data into a list of the given class such as:

```
    public class People
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="people")]
        public IDictionary<string, Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

and than call:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(data);
foreach (var item in obj.Persons.Values)
{
      //item is instance of Person      
}
```

Another good and possible option will be:
[How can I navigate any JSON tree in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946592/how-can-i-navigate-any-json-tree-in-c)

Comment: This does work with json.net.  It does not with the standard Microsoft stuff.  Thanks for the assistance.