# looping through an object passed in via JQUERY as an array and using c# webmethod to get data out

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

all,

I'm getting to my webmethod in my code behind but I'm having problems deserializing my json data.
I have no good reference but here is what I"m trying to do.  My the code in my webmethod is not allowing me to get the data out passed from my ajax call.  thanks for any help.

```
$("[id$=rdbSaveAjax1]").click(function () {

    var mappedJobRole = new Array();

    $(".jobRole").each(function (index) {

        var jobRoleIndex = index;
        var jobRoleID = $(this).attr('id');
        var jobRoleName = $(this).text();

        // add all the roleids and rolenames to the job role array.  
        var roleInfo = {
            "roleIndex": jobRoleIndex,
            "roleID": jobRoleID,
            "roleName": jobRoleName
        };

        queryStr = { "roleInfo": roleInfo };
        mappedJobRole.push(queryStr);

    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Apage.aspx/Save_Mapped_Role",
        data: "{'savedRole': " + JSON.stringify(mappedJobRole) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("successfully posted data");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("failed posted data");
        }

     });

});
```

In my code behind I can't seem to get the data out.
My class:

```
public class MappedRole
{

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

}
```

My webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Save_Mapped_Role(object savedRole)
 {
   bool success = false;
   JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   IList<MappedRole> role = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<MappedRole>>savedRole);
   int Index = role[0].Index;
   string RoleID = role[0].RoleID;
   string RoleName = role[0].RoleName;

    return success;

  }
```

Comment: What does your request and response JSON look like when you use a tool like FireBug or IE Developer tools?

Comment: well in the code behind I can see the data (webmethod) but just don't know of a good way to loop through the data.  I'm not getting any errors on the client side so I haven't been troubleshooting with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be missing an opening parenthese

```
IList<MappedRole> role = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<MappedRole>>savedRole);
```

Should read

```
IList<MappedRole> role = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<MappedRole>>(savedRole);
```

Furthermore, in order to use the Deserialize method, you need to create classes based on the JSON variables you are passing. For example based on the JSON object you created, you should have the two classes below.

**SavedRole Class**

```
public class SavedRole 
{
    public roleInfo[] { get; set; }
}
```

**roleInfo Class**

```
public class roleInfo
{
    public int roleIndex { get; set; }
    public string roleID { get; set; }
    public string roleName { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Deserialze method will do its magic and populate the objects for you. Then you'll be able to loop through the object and do what you need with the data.

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Save_Mapped_Role(object savedRole)
{
   bool success = false;
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   SavedRole role = serializer.Deserialize<SavedRole>(savedRole);

   //Loop through the data like so

   int roleIndex = 0;
   string roleID = null;
   string roleName = null;

   foreach (var item in role.roleInfo) {
       roleIndex =  item.roleIndex;
       roleID = item.roleID;
       roleName = item.roleName;

       //Do more logic with captured data
   }

   return success; 
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

this post explain how you can convert a JSON to C#: [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

If you don't want to use that, you need to do some changes in your project:

First, to get the your RoleInfo, you need to transform it in a Dictionary like:

```
(((object[])savedRole)[0] as Dictionary<string, object>)["roleInfo"]
```

After that, you can manipule your object to create your List:

```
    var list = ((object[])savedRole);

    IList<MappedRole> role = new List<MappedRole>();

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        var dic = ((item as Dictionary<string, object>)["roleInfo"] as Dictionary<string, object>);

        MappedRole map = new MappedRole()
        {
            roleIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dic["roleIndex"]),
            roleID = dic["roleID"].ToString(),
            roleName = dic["roleName"].ToString()

        };

        role.Add(map);
    }
```