# json string comprising of properties use at server side

Tags: asp.net, json

I am currently facing an issue that i have json string which have some properties lets say

```
[
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
    {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
]
```

Now I have to convert this value into some object through which I can iterate and pass it to my business logic.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: this string is passed to server side through hidden field.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Server side to strongly-typed objects: [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Server side to dynamics: [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Client side (with jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/