# Regex to parse a list of items

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like `(Name := Sam&&Age=:17&& Score:=C6)` and a class called Person with around 30 properties - Name, Age, Score, etc. How do I write a regex to parse the string, provided there is a variable number of properties?

Also I was thinking of doing some string replacements to convert the string to a proper JSON and then parse it. Does it sound like a good idea for production code?

I'm using C# 2010.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have := in on place and then =: in another ?

Comment: No, someone has manually edited the DB with inconsistent spaces and equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should match your input string.

```
\(\s*((?<PropertyName>.*?)\s*((:=)|(=:))\s*(?<PropertyValue>.*?)\s*(&&)?\s*)*\)
```

Here's what it means:

```
\(                          Open paren
\s*                         Optional whitespace
(
    (?<PropertyName>.*?)    Property name group
    \s*                     Optional whitespace
    ((:=)|(=:))             Literal ':=' or '=:'
    \s*                     Optional whitespace
    (?<PropertyValue>.*?)   Property value group
    \s*                     Optional whitespace
    (&&)?                   Optional '&&' (the last one won't have one)
    \s*                     Optional whitespace
)*                          The proceeding can repeat 0-many times
\)                          Close paren
```

With this, you can do a match against your string in C#:

```
var regex = new Regex(
    @"\(\s*((?<PropertyName>.*?)\s*((:=)|(=:))\s*(?<PropertyValue>.*?)\s*(&&)?\s*)*\)");
var match = regex.Match(yourString);
```

Then loop through each property/value pair, setting the properties on your object.  Setting the object properties will require some reflection and different code based on the object property types:

```
var properyNames = match.Groups["PropertyName"].Captures;
var properyValues = match.Groups["PropertyValue"].Captures;
var numPairs = propertyNames.Count;

var objType = yourObj.GetType();
for (var i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
{
    var propertyName = propertyNames[i].Value;
    var theValue = propertyValues[i].Value;

    var property = objType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    object convertedValue = theValue;
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        convertedValue = int.Parse(theValue);
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        // ....
    // etc....

    property.SetValue(yourObj, convertedValue, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, very nice :)
What do you think about the conversion to valid JSON, looks like the code will be shorter, but I'm not sure about performance and reliability?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with converting to JSON before parsing; would be some extra unnecessary work, and it can be tricky (you have to deal with escaping some characters).

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely go with the JSON approach. It is much cleaner and robust than relying on a regex.

Take a look at this:
[Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: There are a few, like System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Thx for patching my .NET knowledge, I really have to take a look at these. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

If your separator is &&, then I'd do `String.Split( "&&", myTextString)` when use the regex `(\w+)\s*:=\s*(\w+)` to isolate the key/value pairs.