# JSON in PHP catch in C#

Tags: c#, php, json, json.net

I generate a JSON string in PHP and catch it with httpWebRequest in a .NET windows form application

All works well but I want to use the json.net library to cast that string back to an object (or array).

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
object result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

How can i use that object to get the variables from the JSON string?

I've been working this out all day and couldn't find a way to get all values from the JSON string in C#

All help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a `struct` in your code that matches the JSON object you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(String)` from the [Json.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). It's incredibly easy to use and has implementations for pretty much any .NET version.

You can also use DataContracts which requires no 3rd party library. With DataContracts there are some intermediate steps and code you need to include, but here is a site with a pretty detailed explanation: [Serialization with DataContracts](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx)

Here is a link to a question here on SO that involves Json Serialization using DataContracts: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I think I just found it with the generic jsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(json);

Comment: I have a problem now when I get a list of my database. If I say 'select name,id from companies' in PHP, it returns the correct json string, but how can I catch all those arrays in C#?

Comment: What is an example of the Json string?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 4.0 you can use `dynamic` along with the`JavaScriptConverter` class to [achieve this](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx)