# Parsing JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am getting a response back from a RESTful API in the form of a JSON object.  Normally, I can parse this just fine when the keys are known.  For instance, I create a `User` class like this:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

All I have to do is pull read the response into my JSON deserializer and tell it the output is a <User> and I'm good to go.  This falls short when making other requests, such as sales data.  The response I get back is something like this:

```
{
  "2010-11-24": {
    "country": null,
    "iso": null,
    "product": null,
    "downloads": 39,
    "net_downloads": 38,
    "updates": 6,
    "revenue": "19.02",
    "returns": 1,
    "gift_redemptions": 0,
    "promos": 0
  },
  "2010-11-25": {
    "country": null,
    "iso": null,
    "product": null,
    "downloads": 63,
    "net_downloads": 63,
    "updates": 6,
    "revenue": "37.00",
    "returns": 0,
    "gift_redemptions": 0,
    "promos": 0
  }
}
```

If I could model this class as a `[DataContract]` then I'd be golden, but since the first key is a date, I can't hard code that.

Is there a JSON library out there that can take this kind of response and turn it into a strongly-typed C# class?

For the record, I'm using the [JSONHelper used in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: They key should be represented as `string` or a `DateTime`?

Comment: I'll take it as a string or datetime - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is recognized as the best/fastest/most stable JSON C# library.  I've used it, it works as advertised.

Comment: So, I've downloaded and looked through the documentation.  It looks like I can do exactly what I've done before, create a class to deserialize my JSON into... but I'm still stuck.  How do I deserialize into a class where I don't know the key?