# How to obtain values in JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing, json.net

i have json string as :

```
    {
       "data": [
          {
             "id": "100000045402409_310121622373595",
             "from": {
                "name": "Ritesh Ranjan",
                "id": "100000045402409"
             },
             "message": "greatttttttttttttt ab jaooooooooo",
             "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAGY5rsr5AeM5PI&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.ndtv.com\u00252Fnews\u00252Fimages\u00252Ftopstory_thumbnail\u00252FChidambaram_2G_120.jpg",
             "link": "http://www.ndtv.com/article/india/2g-scam-chidambaram-verdict-expected-shortly-huge-implications-for-govt-173168",
             "name": "2G scam: Chidambaram verdict expected shortly, huge implications for govt",
             "caption": "www.ndtv.com",
             "description": "A Delhi court handling the 2G spectrum allocation scam trial is likely to decide today whether Union Home Minister P Chidambaram should be made a co-accused in the case for allegedly allowing former Telecom Minister A Raja to gift mobile network licenses and scarce second-generation or 2G spectrum a...",
             "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
             "type": "link",
             "application": {
                "name": "Links",
                "id": "2309869772"
             },
             "created_time": "2012-02-04T11:02:22+0000",
             "updated_time": "2012-02-04T11:02:22+0000"
          },
          {
             "id": "100003303253347_132959650157476",
             "from": {
                "name": "Suman Dey",
                "id": "100003303253347"
             },
             "message": "Check out this article I was reading on biNu. 2G verdict: Chidambaram off the hook, government exhales",
             "type": "status",
             "application": {
                "name": "biNu",
                "canvas_name": "binuapp",
                "namespace": "binuapp",
                "id": "378628085054"
             },
             "created_time": "2012-02-04T10:54:19+0000",
             "updated_time": "2012-02-04T10:54:19+0000"
          },
.....
//Continued...
```

Now i want to parse it using c#

i have used :

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                string Json = client.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=2g+verdict+Chidambaram&type=post");
                System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(JsonDestFile);
                SW.WriteLine(Json);

                System.IO.StreamWriter SW1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ValuesDestFile);

                JObject o = JObject.Parse(Json);
var postTitles = from p in o["data"].Children()["from"]
                             select    p["name"].Values<string>();

                        foreach (var item in postTitles)
                        {
                            SW1.WriteLine(item);
                        }
                SW1.WriteLine(name);
```

But i am not able to get any `name` values at all.

Its giving me error : `Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.`

Please suggest me how can i parse the above json for values of  `id, name, id (from one) , message`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working...

```
var postTitles = from p in JO["data"].Children()
                             select new
                             {
                                 Names = (string)p["from"]["name"],
                                 Msg = (string)p["message"],
                             };
```

Using this LINQ i can access the required data.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the LINQ to JSON API, but if you don't insist on using it you can simply create a class that models the data in your JSON payload and then use the following method:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourDataModelClass>()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to deseriralise the json string as shown below

```
public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        var serialiser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serialiser.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Return type is you class

```
public class MyData
{
  public string id { get; set;}
  public string name{ get; set;}
  public string message{ get; set;}
}
```

you can check full details : [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

This also will work

```
JObject hh = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
string name = (string)hh["Name"];
```