# Convert JSON string to C# string array

Tags: c#, json, string, split, stringify

Using JSON.Stringify I pass the following string inside another Stringify object.

```
[
    [
        "I-000-4310-000",
        "Convention Registration",
        "59.99"
    ],
    [
        "I-000-4311-000",
        "Convention Breakout",
        "39.99"
    ]
]
```

In my C# web service I need to split the string apart into a string array that looks like this:

```
 string[, ,] GLCodes = new string[,,] 
 { 
    {
        { "I-000-4310-000", "Convention Registration", "59.99" }, 
        { "I-000-4311-000", "Convention Breakout", "9.99" }
    } 
 };
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Connie take a look at this site and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586585/convert-json-to-a-c-sharp-array

Comment: do you use JSON `JavaScriptSerializer` look here for an example [JavaScriptSerializer](http://atsung.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/javascriptserializer-example/)

Comment: I recommend [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx). Read up about it (or the alternatives), then get back when there is a problem with some *actual* code :D As of right now, this is "not a real question" (or, not more of a question than that which can be succinctly answered in a comment without writing the code for you).

Answer (score 7):

Using Json.NET you can deserialize that list with this

```
string[][] strings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(jsonData);
```

Hope this helps!