# Deserialize a json array in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, vb.net, http-post

i have the following json string from an http post:

```
Dim json As String = "{" + """contacts"":" + "[{" + """name"":""jocelyne" + """," + """mo"":""jocelyne" + """}" + ",{" + """name"":""eliane" + """," + """mo"":""12345678" + """}" + "]}"
```

how can i deserializa this json array? i tried using dictionary but it did not work
note that the length of the json array may be very big

```
 Dim jss As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(json)
 For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dict
        Response.Write(item.Key & " - " & item.Value & "<br>")
    Next
```

Comment: Maybe better idea to deserialize it to custom object?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586585/convert-json-to-a-c-sharp-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ss1 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, string> dicobj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dicobj = ss1.DeserializeObject(JsonString) as Dictionary<string, string>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)**

```
  Dictionary<string,string> deserializedProduct =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but i got this error: `Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'contacts', line 1, position 13.` do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury, then there could be error in JSON format. please check

Comment: i keep getting there is no source code available for the current location although i added the reference to my project and it's in the bin file ..

Comment: can you please check for me the following question: stackoverflow.com/questions/19535504/…

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is `C#` code

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var contacts = obj["contacts"];
```