# How to convert json array to C# object array

Tags: c#, json

i need a help,

i try to convert Json array to C# object array,
here is my json

```
{"jsonString":"{\"MemberSeletedId\":[358753,358754]}"}
```

and this is my c# object class :

```
public class BOMemberSeletedId
{
    public int MemberSeletedId { get; set; }
}
```

how i get a memberselectedid (array) inside json to c# array

here is my convert method at c#

```
public string convert(string jsonString)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<BOMemberSeletedId> param = js.Deserialize<List<BOMemberSeletedId>>(jsonString);

    return param;
}
```

i had tried the solution inside :

[Convert json to a C# array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586585/convert-json-to-a-c-sharp-array)

but still not solve my problem

can some one help ?

thanks

Comment: It appears you have JSON inside a string in that is inside some JSON. You'll need to retrieve that string from the outer JSON and then parse/deserialise the inner JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is declared as a single `int` - despite it being an array in the JSON. It looks like you should be deserializing the JSON to a *single* `BOMembint[erSelectedID`, but the `MemberSeletedId` property should be an `int[]` or `List<int>`:

```
public class BOMemberSeletedId
{
    public List<int> MemberSeletedId { get; set; }
}

BOMemberSeletedId param = js.Deserialize<BOMemberSeletedId>(jsonString);
List<int> values = param.MemberSeletedId;
...
```

(You won't be able to return this directly from your method if your method is declared to return a `string`, of course...)

(I'm assuming that `jsonString` is just `{"MemberSeletedId":[358753,358754]}` by this point.)