# c# json to array debugging "application went to break mode"

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I wanted to convert a json into an array but I get "application went to break mode" when I try debugging mode and the program just freezes down if I try to run it.

I used the answer of 
[Convert json to a C# array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586585/convert-json-to-a-c-sharp-array)
but something went wrong.

Could you help me to find the cause of the error?

```
{
public class MarketHistory
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Order_Count { get; set; }
    public string Volume { get; set; }
    public string Highest { get; set; }
    public string Avarage { get; set; }
    public string Lowest { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static string DownloadString(string address)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string reply = client.DownloadString(address);

        return reply;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        string url = "https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/markets/10000002/history/?datasource=tranquility&type_id=42";
        var json = DownloadString(url);

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        MarketHistory[] marketHistories = js.Deserialize<MarketHistory[]>(json);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

The json:

```
 [
  {
    "date": "2016-11-01",
    "order_count": 24,
    "volume": 275,
    "highest": 28.17,
    "average": 28.15,
    "lowest": 28
  },
```

First fix:

```
{
public class MarketHistory
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string order_count { get; set; }
    public string volume { get; set; }
    public string highest { get; set; }
    public string avarage { get; set; }
    public string lowest { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static string DownloadString(string address)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string reply = client.DownloadString(address);

        return reply;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        string url = "https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/markets/10000002/history/?datasource=tranquility&type_id=42";
        var json = DownloadString(url);

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        MarketHistory[] marketHistories = js.Deserialize<MarketHistory[]>(json);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I added the reference, any idea why can I get the

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Eve_console_app.Program.Main(String[] args)

error?

Comment: Fixed some error.

Comment: For one, the json string does not capitalize the properties like "order_count", but your class has those capitalized.  Order_Count <> order_count.

Comment: Good catch but there is something else too. I'm getting "break mode" both with f5 and ctrl-f5.

Comment: I'm getting 

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Eve_console_app.Program.Main(String[] args)
Press any key to continue . . .

Error message with ctrl - f5 now.

Comment: Then I should just add the dll to the folder?

Comment: I added to the folder, I replaced the dll in the bin folder of the project but still getting the same error.

Comment: Don't add to BIN folder add reference from Assemblies

Comment: okay, I deleted it from the BIN folder, it is only at the references now. Still the same error.

Comment: Could someone help me with any other solution to get an array of objects from the json?

Comment: Use the code I have provided and please mark it as solution if it works for your

Comment: Could you help with a sample code for the data reading part? If I need the 0th line "highest" value in a float variable how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code and make sure to reference `System.Runtime.Serialization` dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
namespace StackOverFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/markets/10000002/history/?datasource=tranquility&type_id=42") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.StatusCode + "\t" + response.StatusDescription);
                }

                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MarketHistory>));
                var result = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as List<MarketHistory>;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class MarketHistory
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string order_count { get; set; }
        public string volume { get; set; }
        public string highest { get; set; }
        public string average { get; set; }
        public string lowest { get; set; }
    }
}
```