# How to call third party Restful API

Tags: c#, rest, endpoints

How could we call the below endpoints in C# webClient, I have managed this with GoogleScript but now I need it in C#

```
      var options = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "method" : "GET",
    "headers" : {
      "X-Api-Key" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "X-Api-Secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://dashboard.reviewpush.com/api/company/locations',options);
  var pages = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

how we can pass headers with multiple values to the request, the code that i have tried is to as below

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://dashboard.reviewpush.com/api/company/locations";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        client.Headers["X-IFORM-API-REQUEST-ENCODING"] = "JSON";
        client.Headers["async"] ="true";
        client.Headers["crossDomain"] = "true";
        client.Headers["method"] = "GET";
        client.Headers["headers"] = "{'X-Api-Key' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          'X-Api-Secret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}";

        Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close();
        reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I think answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948266/c-sharp-json-to-array-debugging-application-went-to-break-mode/47948781#47948781 will help you

Comment: So, what did you try? Do you expect us to do your work?

Comment: Did you RTFM yet? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 -- There is an example right there on the page that you could use as a starting point.

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR That's a bad example using old classes. NewtonSoft.Json with HttpClient should be preferred instead

Comment: Thank you for quick response, @Cam

Comment: Thank you for quick response, @CamiloTerevinto, I don't want any complete code, only thing bothering me is how to pass headers with multiple values to the request. Stuart I have referred the RTFM.

Comment: I don't see that in your question. Please [edit] it and include the relevant code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I have rephrased my query, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing up options of the library with HTTP headers. Try with this instead:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://dashboard.reviewpush.com/api/company/locations";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        client.Headers["X-Api-Key"] = "key";
        client.Headers["X-Api-Secret"] = "secret";

        string s = client.DownloadString(url);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

You might want to look into the recommended `HttpClient` if you can use .NET 4.5 or newer.

Comment: Thanks buddy for the quick fix, I was actually mixing up OPTIONS and headers.