# How to convert an object to an string array?

Tags: c#, .net

i want this:

```
"collection": {
                    "id": "89999999",
                    "amount": "104",
                    "dateCreated": "2022-01-01"
                }
```

to become this

```
"collection": [
                    "id: 89999999",
                    "amount: 104",
                    "dateCreated: 2022-01-01"
              ]
```

ive tried

```
 ((IEnumerable)obj).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()
```

but it crashes with the message "Unable to cast type "myobject" to IEnumerable"

any idea on how to proceed? or how to somehow convert a object/model to an array, specifically an string array, like the example above?

**SOLVED**

added this method to my class

```
        public string[] ConvertToStringArray()
        {

            List<string> lst = new List<string>();

            foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
               if(prop.GetValue(this) != null)
                {
                    lst.Add(prop.Name + ": " + prop.GetValue(this));
                }
            }

            return lst.ToArray();

        }
```

and then, just

```
obj.ConvertToStringArray()
```

Comment: If you know the shape of the object then you can do this manually.  But if you don't know the shape of the object then this will involve using reflection to get its property names/values.

Comment: There are multiple approaches - write custom serializer, use reflection, manually create an array.

Comment: Show us your object definition, please, you can use reflection but perhaps you're having an XY problem

Comment: I assume you've already deserialized since you have a `myobject` class - can you post your classes/code so far? You've only shown one line so we are short on context.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207731/880990).

Comment: You can look at this question. It seems to be the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586585/convert-json-to-a-c-sharp-array

Comment: thanks for the push in the right direction guys, solved it with reflections. Updated original post.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve it.  However, if you share your class definition, we may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: @DanCsharpster im not quite sure what you mean? "obj" is just an object mapped to an model with predefined properties, thats it. Then i use "JsonConvert.SerializeObject" on the whole object to make it json.

Comment: So if this is just a POCO with a bunch of string properties, then this should work.  You may want to ask a few questions, though.  For example, if this class could include nonstring properties, you may want to add a string check like:  if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string)).  Also, if this is just a POCO with a big pile of string properties and you want a generic way to output them, is it possible to just replace your class with a Dictionary<string,string>?  Then it would be even simpler to output and you would gain some extra capabilities.