# Extract property values from the JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON being sent from Postman to my Web API.

```
[
    {
        "salesId": "SO002494"
    },
    {
        "salesId": "SO002496"
    } 
]
```

Sales Model

```cs
public class Sales
{
    public string[] salesId { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
[HttpGet("postRouteOrder")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>>PostRouteOrder([FromBody] Object json)
{
    Sales sales = new Sales();

    sales.salesId = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json.ToString());
           
    //string[] data = { "SO002604", "SO002606" };               
}
```

I want `sales.salesId` to be like data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9586683/13405106

Comment: And it's weird that you post an object via `[HttpGet]`. You should use `[HttpPost]`.

Comment: This is because my web API is an interface between an application and a SOAP API server.  The SOAP API will do the `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest changing the request body parameter type to `List<SaleInput>`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostRouteOrder ([FromBody] List<SaleInput> saleInputs)
{

    string[] data = saleInputs.Select(x => x.SalesId).ToArray();
}
```

```
public class SaleInput
{
    public string SalesId { get; set; }
}
```

---

Apart from that, instead of deserializing as `dynamic`, you should deserialize as `List` of objects and take the `SalesId` as an array.

```
List<SaleInput> saleInput = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SaleInput>>(/* JSON */);

sales.salesId = saleInputs.Select(x => x.SalesId)
        .ToArray();
```