# How to Json Parsing In asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=gettopstoriestabnews
```

This is my web service I have to parse and store all value in `String` please help me how to parse.

using asp.net (C#) so that I can store :

```
news_id  as it variable

news_title as  title variable

news_short_description   as description

news_date as date ;
```

Please help me I'm new in .net I tried but not able to do

Comment: *Please* don't use **"plz"** but **"please"**.

Comment: I guess even better would have been "plz don't use 'plz' but 'please' " :P

Comment: maybe this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this class

```
public class News
{
    public string news_id;
    public string news_title;
    public string news_short_description;
    public string news_date;
}
```

to deserialize the response string

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result =  serializer.Deserialize<News[]>(wc.DownloadString("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=gettopstoriestabnews"));
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.news_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanyou very much i got oout put i want this thing

Comment: can u plz bind the data so that we can display in listview

Comment: @AnilKumar You asked something and got your answer. You canceled your `accept` since I didn't answer your **second** question? Not nice. Don't be a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Answer (score 2):

First download a JSON library from [here](http://json.codeplex.com/). And add reference to your project (Right click to your project=>Add reference=> NewtonSoft.Json.dll).  After that do some coding...

```
using System.Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString("http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=gettopstoriestabnews");

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);
        Response.Write("NewsID: "+ o["news_id"]);
        Response.Write("NewsTitle: " + o["news_title"]);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "DataContractJsonSerializer" instead of JavaScriptSerializer, it's the component used by WCF to (de)serialize JSON
Read this for more info: http://publicityson.blogspot.com/2010/06/datacontractjsonserializer-versus.html

Comment: Avoid DCJS. It's less flexible when [de]serializing Enums, DateTimes, Anonymous Types, and produces larger than necessary (incorrect, IMO) JSON for Dictionaries.

Comment: Yes there are drawback. But JavaScriptSerializer doesn't handle recursivity correctly (if you have object referencing itself via references to other objects). So each components have pro & cons, it's why I linked the article.

Comment: @Fabske `You can also use "DataContractJsonSerializer" instead of JavaScriptSerializer` OP doesn't use anything. This is not an answer, just a comment to my answer. And I, personally, prefer [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) whenever I have the option to choose.