# ASP.net (VB code behind) JSON parsing facebook Graph API response

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

net but wanted to try to do this code in ASP.net instead of my normal classic ASP.

I have been trying to find code examples that would show me how to parse out the name & id in a returned JSON from a facebook API Graph call. The JSON return looks like this from Facebook:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "David xxxxxx", 
      "id": "05121212", 
      "administrator": true
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Billy xxxxxxx", 
      "id": "0005128888"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxx/members?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=xxxxx"
  }
}
```

Any examples on how to go about parsing out just the name and id from the JSON response in ASP.net would be awesome!

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for, http://james.newtonking.com/

```
string response = <your fb data>;   // I am lazy :P
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(response);
JArray data = (JArray)obj["data"];
for(int i=0,int len=data.count; i < len ; i++)
{
 string name = data[i]["name"].ToString();
 string id = data[i]["id"].ToString();
 string administrator = string.Empty;
 if(data[i]["administrator"]!=null)
 {
   string administrator = data[i]["administrator"].ToString();
 }

}
```

I think, this code is enough to get you going.
Always check for null as api data may or may not have that value.

Edit: I noticed that you wanted a VB code, sorry. But it may help others, so leaving it here. You can convert the code from any C# to VB convertor.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not there is a known library for .NET and Open Graph, Json is Json.  The way I see it you have three options:

1) Use Newtonsoft Json.  You can install this package using nuget into your ASP.NET project and from there there are lots of places on the web that talk about working with this library.  http://james.newtonking.com/ is the home page of the library, there are also posts here.

2) Use .NET Json.  Again, lots of info on the web here.  I found a pretty good looking post here [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

3) Use the C# Facebook SDK.  The FacebookClient class has the ability to serialize and de-serialize Json.  You can also install this library via Nuget.  I admit the documentation on the C# SDK is lacking, but none the less it works well.  More information about it can be found here: http://blog.prabir.me/category/Facebook-C-SDK.aspx

I hope this helps you down the right path.

-Eric

Comment: http://aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?t=233749 There is a VB link.  I noticed you asked about VB and I provided C# links, sorry about that.  I tried to edit the post but got an error about the # of links, yet it let me submit the post to begin with. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

There are no known supported libraries for .net for the new graph api.  https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk  has a few samples for using .net though.