# How can I pass a javascript multidimensional array to c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, code-behind

I need to pass a js multidimensional array (the dimensions are not known at compile time) to my code-behind in c#, I have done this in the next way:

```
var AdjustItems = ""; //My string variable to store the array separated with '|' and '-'
for (var i = 0; i < adjusts.length; i++) { //adjusts is my js array
    AdjustItems += adjusts[i].Motive + '|' + adjusts[i].Amount.toFixed(2).toString() + '-';
}
if (AdjustItems != "") {
    AdjustItems = AdjustItems.substring(0, AdjustItems.length - 1);
}
g('arrAdjust').value = AdjustItems; //arrAdjust is my hidden input.
```

Is there another way to do this where I can get the array, like an array and not like a string in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there another way to do this where I can get the array, like an
>   array and not like a string in c#?

The only way to communicate between the client and server is with strings. Therefore, you must use a library like [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/) to pass complex variables between the client and server.

You can use javascript's [built-in JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) library to turn your array into a string. This would change your example to the following:

```
g('arrAdjust').value = JSON.stringify(adjusts);
```

Then, use a C# `JSON` parsing library to convert it to an array on the server side. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp) may help you with C# and parsing the JSON.