# Returning and displaying a JSON Object which is an associate array in a Windows 8 App

Tags: json, web-services, windows-8

I am using a online tutorial to lean how to create a web service, generate a JSON object, send it back to my Win 8 App and display it. The web service is working however I am struggling to return a value to the APP. My code in the app is:

```
 WinJS.xhr({                         
         url: 'http://localhost/filmgloss/web-service.php?termID=1&format=JSON'
     })
         .done(
            function complete(result) {

                // terms is the key of the object
                for (var terms in result) {

                    for (var term in terms) {


                        if (result.hasOwnProperty(term)) {
                            //here you have to acess to
                            var termName = result[term].termName;
                            var def = result[term].definition;
                        }
                        //Show Terms                 
                        testDef.innerText = definition;
                    }
                }
            },
```

And he code in my web service is:

```
if($format == 'json') {
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode(array('terms'=>$terms));
}else...
```

The JSON output itself looks like:

```
    {"terms":[{"term":{ "termName":"Focus","definition":"A Focus..."}}]}
```

I am using a `for..in` but whilst I can look inside `terms' I can't work out how to look in`term`

Comment: If you are returning a JSON String, shouldn't the content type be String?  Otherwise, you are trying to parse something that isn't a string.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. The web service returns the JSON values in an array. The full tutorial is here, I have simply changed a few variable names, nothing else - http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Comment: If it's an array, then it is not a string.  Don't try parse it.

Comment: I have revised the question after your help, thanks.

Comment: JSON.parse(response) will give you the data to work with.

Comment: I thought JSON.parse works only with a JSON string and not an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve my issue with the help of a developer friend. My problem was that I had not realised that the result of `WinHS.xhr` was not already a JSON Array. Although my web-service outputs a JSON Array when it is consumed through `WinHS.xhr` it appears to be returned as an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

The solution was therefore to process the result using:

`JSON.parse(result.responseText)`

I could then use a `For...In` loop as expected:

```
  for (terms in responseTerms) {

             //terms will find key "terms"
             var termName = responseTerms.terms[0].term.termName;
             var termdefinition = responseTerms.terms[0].term.definition;

             testTerm.innerText = termName;
             testDef.innerText = termdefinition;

         }
```

Thanks for everyone that commented, hopefully this may help others in the future if they're starting out with Win 8 app development.

Answer (score 0):

I usually build my own data structure that represents the JSON structure.
In your case it would be something like this:

```
public class TermsList
{
    public List<Term> terms { get; set; } 
}

public class Term
{
    public string termName { get; set }
    public definition termName { get; set }
    ...
}
```

Then you can just deserialize your string into your object. There are different ways to do this. I would use Json.Net.
Here is one way:
[Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

```
public static T Deserialise<T>(string json)
{
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms); // <== Your missing line
        return obj;
    } 
}
```

If you wanna keep it dynamic, that should work too:

http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

Comment: Thanks Remy for taking the time to add an answer, unfortunately I'm working with HTML, JavaScript and CSS for the Win 8 app. Do you know the equivalent in javascript rather than C#? Thanks

Comment: Silly me! Did you just try result[1].definition?