# .NET classes needed to deserialize JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, json, json.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string from the openlibrary.org in an ASP.NET (4.5) web application using JSON.NET.

My aim is to be able to read the 5 properties below from a single .Net object.

The [example JSON](http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0201558025&format=json)
 I have is:

```
{"ISBN:0201558025": 
    {
        "bib_key": "ISBN:0201558025",
        "preview": "noview",
        "thumbnail_url": "http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/135182-S.jpg",
        "preview_url": "http://openlibrary.org/books/OL1429049M/Concrete_mathematics",
        "info_url": "http://openlibrary.org/books/OL1429049M/Concrete_mathematics"
    }
}
```

I can get it to work fine without the first line, but I'm a bit lost trying to work out how I should structure my classes.

I'm new to JSON and haven't played with C#/VB.NET in a few years so getting very lost.

**Update**

I have the following code:

```
Dim url = "http://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0201558025&format=json"
Dim webClient = New System.Net.WebClient
Dim json = webClient.DownloadString(url)

Dim book As Book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Book)(json)
```

And the class Book:

```
Public Class Book
    Public bib_key As String
    Public preview As String
    Public preview_url As String
    Public info_url As String
End Class
```

However, book turns up empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is a website called [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) - generate c# classes from json:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string bib_key { get; set; }
    public string preview { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    public string preview_url { get; set; }
    public string info_url { get; set; }
}
```

The json format is a little off, remove the {"ISBN:0201558025": since you have the ISBN as the `bib_key`

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but wasn't sure about the ISBN bit. The problem I'm having now is that my book object isn't receiving the details, which lead me to think I may be missing a class.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**JSON.Net**](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

or

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) Class

or

[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be deserialized as a Dictionary.

```
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, BookInfoClass>>(jsonString);
```