# How to elegantly parse the following text into a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, regex, json, parsing

I have the following text that I need to put into a dictionary. At first sight I thought that it would be very easy but at the end I found myself doing extensive string search and finding sometimes values that break the parser.

```
"0": 
{
    "key":"valueWithAnyCharInside",
    "key2":"valueWithAnyCharInside",
    "key3":"valueWithAnyCharInside" 
},
```

This will map into the following model:

```
class Item
{
    private int id;
    private Dictionary<string, string> data;
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe using regex ...

Comment: Hmmm isn't this JSON ? If no, what's the expected output ?

Comment: This text is a JSON fragment. Parse the input into objects and then project those into anything you like. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: As previously mentioned, this is JSON data, and parsing it would be more powerful than any regex you can ever dream of. Please don't use regex for this.

Comment: @Kooki: i think it's clear enough on the question. I implemented it with string searching and parsing.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. So it's JSON. Can someone answer the question so I can approve it? Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data format is probably a JSON, but you gave only a part of it. I've modified it slightly as:

```
{"0":
    {
        "key":"valueWithAnyCharInside",
        "key2":"valueWithAnyCharInside",
        "key3":"valueWithAnyCharInside" 
    }
}
```

now you can parse it as following:

```
string json = ...; //your json goes here

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var parsed =  serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);

//printing data
parsed["0"].Select(pair => string.Format( "{0} - {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value))
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

prints:

```
key - valueWithAnyCharInside
key2 - valueWithAnyCharInside
key3 - valueWithAnyCharInside
```

---

To get strongly typed `List<Item>` use next code

```
List<Item> items = parsed.Select(pair => new Item { Id = int.Parse(pair.Key),
                                                    Data = pair.Value})
                         .ToList();
```

Where Item is :

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Right, that was the full output ;)