# matching specific characters using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like :

```
"{
\"__type\":\"DailyRequestItem:#CapitalIQ.DataAPI.Download\",
\"Identifier\":{\"__type\":\"CompanyIdentifier:#CapitalIQ.DataAPI\",\"SearchString\":\"goog\"},
\"FormulaMetric\":{\"MetricName\":\"IQ_LASTSALEPRICE\",\"MetricId\":0},
\"ReturnType\":0,
\"CurrencyConversionInfo\":{\"CurrencyId\":160,\"CurrencyConversionMode\":0},\"Response\":{
\"Id\":0,\"CompanyId\":29096,\"TradingItemId\":11311662,\"RequestedCurrencyId\":0,\"CurrencyConversionModeId\":0,\"Error\":0,\"Values\":[{\"CurrencyConversionDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\\/\",\"DataTypeId\":2,\"ReportedCurrencyId\":0,\"Id\":0,\"CurrencyId\":160,\"ScaleId\":0,\"UnitsId\":0,\"ValueId\":0,\"ValueAsString\":\"896.598000\",\"Delimiter\":\",\",\"SubValueList\":null,\"Error\":0,\"ClickThroughTypeId\":0,\"InstanceId\":0,\"PricingDate\":\"\\/Date(1374724800000-0400)\\/\",\"ConversionMode\":0,\"AuditabilityTypeId\":0,\"AsOfDate\":\"\\/Date(1374724800000-0400)\\/\",\"CompanyId\":0,\"DataItemId\":0,\"TradingItemId\":0}]
},
\"RangeInfo\":{\"AsOfDate\":\"\\/Date(1374724800000-0400)\\/\",\"StartDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"EndDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"Frequency\":1,\"ReturnType\":0,\"TradingDayOffset\":null,\"IsIntraday\":false},\"Period\":null}"
```

from which I need to remove this part:

```
\"Response\":{
\"Id\":0,\"CompanyId\":29096,\"TradingItemId\":11311662,\"RequestedCurrencyId\":0,\"CurrencyConversionModeId\":0,\"Error\":0,\"Values\":[{\"CurrencyConversionDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\\/\",\"DataTypeId\":2,\"ReportedCurrencyId\":0,\"Id\":0,\"CurrencyId\":160,\"ScaleId\":0,\"UnitsId\":0,\"ValueId\":0,\"ValueAsString\":\"896.598000\",\"Delimiter\":\",\",\"SubValueList\":null,\"Error\":0,\"ClickThroughTypeId\":0,\"InstanceId\":0,\"PricingDate\":\"\\/Date(1374724800000-0400)\\/\",\"ConversionMode\":0,\"AuditabilityTypeId\":0,\"AsOfDate\":\"\\/Date(1374724800000-0400)\\/\",\"CompanyId\":0,\"DataItemId\":0,\"TradingItemId\":0}]
},
```

and serialize it. I'm using this regex but to no avail:

```
string pattern = @"\\Response\.\]}";
```

Can someone help me out to form the regex pattern please? Please help

Comment: yes, it's a json string

Comment: Are you able to use a JSON library to parse it and extract the part you need?

Comment: I was planning on using Regex, still trying on that..not sure if I got your question, but I am using JSON serializer to parse it into a Request item, which has a Response(child) element..but the problem is the Response item has this XmlIgnore in its data contract, so once I serialize the json string and do Request.Response = null, the Response is still there...have no isea how to progress :(

Comment: Why in the world would you be trying to parse JSON with a regex when there are much better solutions?

Comment: much better solns like?

Comment: A quick search here using `[c#] parse JSON` returned [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1212344/62576) as the first result. You should learn to search (here or via Google). :-)

Comment: Not very serious: I'm afraid that helping you to come up with regular expression dealing with nested braces/quotes and like can be considered intention to harm... Please save us from helping you to hurt yourself and use existing JSON parser like JSON.Net.

Comment: Deserialize JSON -> dynamic, profit.

Comment: For more on the perils of using regexes for this stuff, [see this classic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1053021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people suggest to parse a JSON response regex is not an appropriate solution, but still if you do not find any other solution you can use this pattern to resolve your issue:

```
(\"Response\")[\S\s]*?(?=\"RangeInfo\")
```

Have a look at this [rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/xsoeRwkr0L).

#### NOTE:

I expect the JSON response will be always in a specific format and `RangeInfo` element will be the next upcoming node in the JSON response.