# I want get json parse data in C#

Tags: c#, json

This is my JObject.Parse string.

```
{"topic":{"account_id":190884,"created_at":"2015-01-31T16:35:59+05:00","delta":true,"forum_id":5000225377,"hits":0,"id":5000025527,"import_id":null,"last_post_id":5000040596,"locked":false,"merged_topic_id":null,"posts_count":0,"published":true,"replied_at":"2015-01-31T16:35:59+05:00","replied_by":5005399997,"stamp_type":null,"sticky":0,"title":"I want use API of Freshdesk.","updated_at":"2015-01-31T16:35:59+05:00","user_id":5005399997,"user_votes":0,"posts":[{"account_id":190884,"answer":false,"body":" I want to use API of Freshdesk to get forums of Freshdesk. I want to access users and posts from different Forums and show that data in my Application. I want to develop C# console Application.\u00a0  Anyone please help me. \r\n","body_html":"\u003Cp\u003EI want to use API of Freshdesk to get forums of Freshdesk. I want to access users and posts from different Forums and show that data in my Application. I want to develop C# console Application.\u00a0\u003C/p\u003E\u003Cp\u003EAnyone please help me.\u003C/p\u003E\r\n","created_at":"2015-01-31T16:35:59+05:00","forum_id":5000225377,"id":5000040596,"import_id":null,"published":true,"spam":null,"topic_id":5000025527,"trash":false,"updated_at":"2015-01-31T16:35:59+05:00","user_id":5005399997}]}}
```

I want to get values of (posts) from this string in C#. Anyone can help me how i can get values of posts from this string.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: There is quite a lot of similar questions on SO. See e.g. this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Use Newtonsoft's Json.net

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

It is an easy to use library:

Example:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
  'Action',
  'Comedy'
]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

Comment: I include newtonsoft in my application. but it's not helpful for me.
I also try this. In test there is my string.
here is my other classes.
public class Topic
{
public int account_id { get; set; }
public ICollection<Post> posts { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
public int account_id { get; set; }
public bool answer { get; set; }
public string body { get; set; }
public string body_html { get; set; }
}
Topic ABC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(test);
when i debug it and check the value of ABC. there is null value shows.

Comment: In the given string there is an extra level which contains the "topic" object.
Add this class:
    public class Root{public Topic topic { get; set; }}
and then just call Root ABC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(test);

Comment: This will not work in .netcore

Answer (score 1):

```
var s=<json_string>;
var firstPost = JObject.Parse(s)["topic"]["posts"][0];
string postBody = (string)firstPost["body"];
```