# How can I parse JSON to a C# object?

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON data that I need to access from C#. The chapters element looks like this:

```
"chapters": [
    [
      2, 
      1416420134.0, 
      "2", 
      "546cdb2645b9efbff4582d51"
    ], 
    [
      1, 
      1411055241.0, 
      null, 
      "541afe8945b9ef69885d3d74"
    ], 
    [
      0, 
      1414210972.0, 
      "0", 
      "544b259c45b9efb061521235"
    ]
]
```

Here are my C# classes that are meant to contain that data:

```
public class test
{
    public string[] chapters { get; set; }
}

public class TChapter
{
    public test[] aa { get; set; }
}
```

How can I parse the JSON to C# objects?

Comment: take a look at `Newtonsoft.JSON`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What makes you think your classes represent your json?

Comment: Is that just so?

Comment: I do not fully understand english

Json data [ and [   data[i][0]

Comment: Please use http://json2csharp.com/ to get the correct class to map to your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Using Newtonsoft JSON you will want to do something like the following

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonDeserializationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var chaptersAsJson = "[" +
                                 "    [" +
                                 "        2," +
                                 "        1416420134.0," +
                                 "        \"2\"," +
                                 "        \"546cdb2645b9efbff4582d51\"" +
                                 "    ], " +
                                 "    [" +
                                 "        1," +
                                 "        1411055241.0," +
                                 "        null," +
                                 "        \"541afe8945b9ef69885d3d74\"" +
                                 "    ], " +
                                 "    [" +
                                 "        0," +
                                 "        1414210972.0," +
                                 "        \"0\"," +
                                 "        \"544b259c45b9efb061521235\"" +
                                 "    ]" +
                                 "]";
            var chaptersAsTwoDObjectArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[][]>(chaptersAsJson);

            // Use the chapters array
            foreach (object[] chapter in chaptersAsTwoDObjectArray)
            {
                // what do you want to do with the object array?
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", chapter));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your classes don't line up with your JSON.

Comment: So your chapters element is an array of object arrays? And those object arrays contain an integer, a decimal, a string, and a string? Did you design this JSON? Can it be changed? What is the purpose of the four objects in the object array?