# how to get value of json data in c#

Tags: c#, json

Im getting json data through webservice..and i want put data from **lstResponsewrap** into table or Repeater in c#..how to do this ..

```
    {
    "Success": true,
    "Status": "Success",
    "serviceLogs": [],
    "PaymentTerms": [
        {
            "strUnitName": "TS MSQ JN1-12-1201",
            "propertyInventoryId": "a0KP0000001fwB3MAI",
            "lstResponsewrap": [
                {
                    "TERMDAYS": "0",
                    "TERMDATE": "2017-11-29",
                },
                {
                    "TERMDAYS": "1",
                    "TERMDATE": "2017-10-3",
                }],
              }]}
```

c# Code

```
        using (var response = httpReq.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string dr = reader.ReadToEnd();

             var myRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(dr);
            var roote = myRoot.PaymentTerms;

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you add more information; where is this JSON data, is it in a plain text file, in an object, in a string. What table are you trying to get it to MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL etc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you provide some more information someone will be able to help but as it stands we don't know enough about what you're trying to do and what problems you've seen. Cheers!

Comment: There are a number of options for processing JSON. [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/10.0.3) is generally the preferred one.

Comment: OK so presumably roote.lstResponsewrap exists does it? When you say 'table' is it a database table you are talking about? Does the code you are working with have any existing way of writing to tables, or is the whole concept of writing to a table new here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Comment: We have no info on the table or the repeater in  "lstResponsewrap into table or Repeater". And you can have more than 1 lstResponsewrap .