# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when trying to add Custom Object to Custom List

Tags: c#, list, object

I am attempting to convert the price and product names from a json file into a C# usable format. for this I have written a customized json converter.
The Code goes as follows:

```
//using various stuff...
public class ProductData
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductList
{
    public List<ProductData> Data { get; set; }
}
public class program
{
     public static async Task Main()
     {
     //various stuff to retrieve the json string...
     ProductList market = CustomJsonParser(json);
     //...
     }
     
     public static ProductList CustomJsonParser(string json)
     {
     ProductList market = new ProductList();
        int angl_brkt_start = json.IndexOf("[", 0)+1;
        int circ_brkt_start = json.IndexOf("{", angl_brkt_start)+1;

        while(circ_brkt_start >= 0)
        {
            ProductData product = new ProductData();

            int name_field_start = json.IndexOf("name\": ", circ_brkt_start) + 7;
            int name_field_stop = json.IndexOf(",", name_field_start);
            string product_name = json.Substring(name_field_start, name_field_stop - name_field_start).Replace("\"", "");

            int price_field_start = json.IndexOf("price\": ", name_field_stop) + 8;
            int price_field_stop = json.IndexOf(",", price_field_start);
            string product_price_string = json.Substring(price_field_start, price_field_stop -  price_field_start);
            
            int product_price = int.Parse(product_price_string);

            product.Name = product_name;
            product.Price = product_price;

            Console.WriteLine(product.Name + "\t" + product.Price);
            market.Data.Add(product); // <-- Exception gets raised here



            circ_brkt_start = html.IndexOf("{", price_field_stop);
        }
        return market;
     }
}
```

If I look at product.Name and product.Price for each entry I can see both being outputted to Console like:
Apple  10
Banana 15
...
However the `market.Data.Add(product)` gives an error claiming that ProductList.Data.get returned null

I have already tried to output product.Price and product.Name to see if they were indeed null and they are not. Since I am new to C#, I guess I have just declared something wrong.

Comment: `ProductList market = new ProductList { Data  = new List<ProductData>()};` or declare correct default value for the property.

Comment: Just curious: why in the world would you do custom parsing of json?

Comment: _"I have already tried to output product.Data"_  How? It's not shown in the code.

Comment: Maybe useful for the parsing of JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp